# How to tell which SATA controller a drive is using?

Tags: linux, sata

My motherboard has three separate SATA controllers each in their own IOMMU group. Two ASMedia controllers and the one in the Intel PCH.

I want to make sure my main drives are using the Intel controller.

How can I see which SATA controllers are being used and for which drives?

Looking for GNU/Linux commands that display text info.

**EDIT**:
Here's my `lshw -class storage -class disk` output:

```
*-storage                 
    description: SATA controller
    product: ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller
    vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
*-storage
    description: SATA controller
    product: ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller
    vendor: ASMedia Technology Inc.
*-storage
    description: SATA controller
    product: 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
    vendor: Intel Corporation
*-scsi:0
    physical id: 1
    logical name: scsi2
    capabilities: emulated
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
*-scsi:1
    physical id: 2
    logical name: scsi3
    capabilities: emulated
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
*-scsi:2
    physical id: 3
    logical name: scsi4
    capabilities: emulated
  *-disk
       description: ATA Disk
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
```

Comment: The motherboard manual will indicate which ports on the board belong to which controller

Comment: That's fine but I'm really looking for some commands like `lspci` and `lsusb`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The device hierarchy is available in `/sys`, if you don't want to do it manually, you can use `udevadm`:

```
$ udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sda
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata1/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0/block/sda
```

So on my system, `/dev/sda` is SCSI unit `0:0:0:0`, and the SATA controller has PCI id `0000:00:1f.2`, which is the Intel PCH controller:

```
$ lspci
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
```

Comment: Awesome! This is perfect. I would upvote you but I don't have 15 rep.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/block |grep -I "sd*"
```

Then `lspci | grep SATA` to find it